# Python code is weirdly jumping to the except block

Tags: python

So I am going nuts here trying to figure out what is happening, I have added a TON of print statements to see what is going on with the code and I cannot make any sense of why it is jumping around like it is...

I know the code looks hacky, and it is, but I cannot see why it is jumping into the except block....

The output I get is this:

```
add audio function
makinf file list
doing if statement
[]
before try
inside try
Is there an audio file_URL ready?:
```

The code is below, it seems to be missing print statement and just disintegrating somewhere and jumping to the except block....

```
def add_audio(self, word):
    '''function for adding audio path to a word'''
    print "add audio function"
    path = "mypath/%s/" % (self.language_ISO)
    print 'makinf file list' 
    existing_file = glob.glob("%s/%s.*" % (path, word)) + glob.glob('%s/%s[0-9].*' % (path, word))
    print ' doing if statement'
    print existing_file
    if existing_file:
        print 'into if statement'
        if self.choice("\nThere is an existing audio file for this word...\nWould you like to add another?: "):
            add_another = True
            print add_another
        else:   
            return (existing_file, "N/A")
    print 'before try'
    try:
        print "inside try"
        if add_another:
            print 'about to raise error'
            #Made this variable and thre an error to force the except loop to run and add another file
            raise NameError('throwing an intentional error as a hack')
        print 'made it past try but failed somewhere else'
        wiktionary_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://%s.wiktionary.org/wiki/FILE:en-us-%s.ogg" % (self.wiktionary_prefix, word))
        print 'made it past try but failed somewhere fromstring'
        wiktionary_page = fromstring(wiktionary_page.read())
        print 'made it past try but failed somewhere xpath'
        file_URL = wiktionary_page.xpath("//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' fullMedia ')]/a/@href")[0]
        print 'made it past try but failed somewhere wget'
        os.popen("wget -O %s/%s.ogg --progress=bar 'http:%s'" % (path, word, file_URL))
        print("\nFile Downloaded from wiktionary successfully!\n")
        return ("%s/%s.ogg" % (path, word), file_URL)
    except:
        if self.choice("Is there an audio file_URL ready?: "):
            file_URL = raw_input("What is the file_URL?: ")
            print "\n%s\n" % (file_URL)
            while not self.choice("Is this correct?: "):
                file_URL = raw_input("What is the file_URL")
                time.sleep(.5)
                print "\n%s\n" % (file_URL)
            file_extension = file_URL.split('.')[-1]
            file_number = len(existing_file)
            file_path_name = "%s/%s%d.%s" % (path, word, file_number, file_extension)
            os.popen("wget -O %s --progress=bar '%s'" % (file_path_name, file_URL))
            return ("%s/%s%d.%s" % (file_path_name, file_URL))
        elif not existing_file:
            with open(self.logfile, 'a') as f:
                f.write("AUDIO: Need to record audio for %s\n" % (word))
            return ("/", "N/A")
```

Comment: My guess: `add_another` doesn't exist. But you'd be able to tell for sure if you captured the exception and printed it out (or didn't capture it at all).

Comment: omg I cannot believe I missed that, thanks

Comment: (I edited your question to say "except block" instead of "except loop.")

Comment: Change the last `elif` to an `else`, i suspect that you will see something happen.

Comment: Generally, it's a Good Idea™ to use named exceptions; "naked" `except` blocks are rarely useful (unless they're at the end of a bunch of named `except` blocks, and even then they should generally print some useful info and/or re-raise the exception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I should have been doing was exactly what @smarx said. I should have been printing the exception by doing this

```
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
```

That will print the exception that is being raised and help me to debug where it went wrong. Outside of that I should have been custom handling different kinds of exceptions

Comment: Sometime (depending on the circumstance), while debugging I just comment out my `try` and `except` just to see the error. But, albeit, the `except Exception as e` with a `print` is a more elegant solution.